# Autowire using "byName" ignores the autowire-candidate=false configuration

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

According to [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-autowire-candidate) of Spring Framework Reference documentation, when `autowire-candidate` is set to `false` in a bean's XML definition, it excludes the bean from the autowiring infrastructure. The section doesn't talk about any exceptions to this case.

This works when `autowire` is set to `byType`. But when it is set to `byName`, the `autowire-candidate="false"` configuration is ignored and the bean is still autowired.

My question is:

- Is this by design and not documented (or)
- Is it a bug (or)
- Am I missing something in my configuration?

Following is the list of relevant source listings:

**MovieDataStore.java**

```
public class MovieDataStore {
    // Just some dummy class
}
```

**MovieDao.java**

```
public class MovieDao {
    private MovieDataStore movieDataStore;

    public MovieDataStore getMovieDataStore() {
        return movieDataStore;
    }

    public void setMovieDataStore(MovieDataStore movieDataStore) {
        this.movieDataStore = movieDataStore;
    }
}
```

**spring-context.xml snippet**

```
<bean id="movieDao" class="com.example.spring.MovieDao" autowire="byName"/>

<bean id="movieDataStore" class="com.example.spring.MovieDataStore" 
        autowire-candidate="false"/>
```

**Testing code**

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx;
ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");

MovieDao movieDao = ctx.getBean("movieDao", MovieDao.class);

System.out.println(movieDao.getMovieDataStore());

ctx.close();
```

I am expecting it to print `null` because the only dependency that I asked to autowire is actually excluded from autowiring. But, the above testing code prints this:

```
com.example.spring.MovieDataStore@22915056
```

Note that this happens only in case of autowire `byName`. If I autowire `byType`, it prints `null` as expected.

I am using Spring Framework version 4.3.5.RELEASE and Java 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this Spring JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15072) which I raised, it is by design and not documented.

Comment from Juergen Hoeller on the ticket:

> This is an old design decision where autowire-candidate="false" only affects type-based autowiring attempts, not direct references by name... and not autowire="byName" either. While the latter may be debatable, I'm not inclined to change it at this point since autowire="byName" is an outdated mechanism to begin with. I'm therefore turning this into a documentation issue.